# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in solution to CodingBat maxBlock

Tags: java

1. I'm new here so no flame please.
2. I know i can just find solutions online and i did, but i just can't understand how the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error is happening in my code.

```java
public int maxBlock(String str) {

    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
        int c1 = 0;
        for(int j = i + 1; i < str.length(); j++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j) && j - i == 1)
                c1++;
        }
        if(c1 > max)
            max = c1;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Edit: Resolved :D

Comment: Typo: `int j = i + 1; i < str.length(); j++` ----> `int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++`. Copy-paste fail :).

Comment: What is the error? If you try to follow the rule here, nobody will scold you, relax

Comment: @Tunaki Holy hell, thanks man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs at the last iteration in the for loop when `i` reaches the final value, because `str.charAt(j)` cannot be reached (`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`) as `j` is `i + 1`

Simply put, when it reaches the last character in the first `for` loop, it cannot find the character at index `j` when you use `str.charAt(j)`